# Error APNS device token not set before retrieving FCM Token for Sender ID '#########'

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, firebase-messaging, refreshtoken

Estoy recibiendo mensajes de fireabse para notificaciones con APNs, en firebase tengo el certificado de APNs key, con el mismo id en el proyecto de Xcode en Firebase que se extrae desde Apple Developer.

Pero no se porque puede estar pasando esto y sale este error y se me esta registrando dos tokens en la extension de Messaging:

```
extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
  func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {}}
```

> APNS device token not set before retrieving FCM Token for Sender ID
> '########'. Notifications to this FCM Token will not be delivered
> over APNS.Be sure to re-retrieve the FCM token once the APNS device
> token is set.

Agrego lo que tengo en el AppDelegate

```
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate{

    var firebaseToken: String = ""
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FirebaseApp.configure()
        self.registerForFirebaseNotification(application: application)
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        return true
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    }

    func registerForFirebaseNotification(application: UIApplication) {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
    
}

extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

//MessagingDelegate
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
        self.firebaseToken = fcmToken!
        print("Firebase token: \(fcmToken)")
    }

    //UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        print("APNs received with: \(userInfo)")
     }
}
```

Comment: Aclaro no me están llegando notificación ni por api ni por consola de Firebase

Comment: Estás haciendo pruebas en el simulador o en el iPhone? Si es en el iPhone, cómo obtienes el ssuid?

Comment: @Bicho, estoy haciendo pruebas desde celular fisico, antes no me aparecía esto pero desde ayer me empezó a salir ese mensaje y ya no me llegan mensajes de cloud messaging de firebase. El ssuid?, se refiere al sender Id?

Comment: @Bicho, no se cómo saber si esta almacenado en firebase, en caso si eso es lo que esta afectando como lo puedo hacer desde el AppDelegate?.

Comment: @Bicho yo realice esta misma configuración : https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration/

Comment: Creo que la asignación del token no es la correcta. Que te imprime `deviceToken` en esta línea `Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken`

Comment: @Bicho Me imprime esto fAwe2DUxbj32zoyCAxWN4zWPgTrBQVbl378TlkOgJtM=, de la siguiente manera: Messaging.messaging().apnsToken?.base64EncodedString().He estado leyendo en muchos foros este error y no encuentran solución, unos dicen que es actualizar pods pero no me funciono, otros que por el certificado de APNs, pero el certificado APNs key no tiene vencimiento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución fue:

- Colocar **application.registerForRemoteNotifications()** encima de **FirebaseApp.configure()**.

  Sacado de: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43534486/ios-swift-firebase-instanceid-token-returns-nil-at-first-time
- Agregar el siguiente fragmento de código:

  Sacado de: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44128932/i-am-not-able-to-receive-data-notification-ios-swift-3

> func application(_ application: UIApplication,
> didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
> Messaging.messaging()
> .setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: MessagingAPNSTokenType.unknown)
> }

Comment: Puedes marcar como solución a tu respuesta, así ayudas a otros con el mismo problema.

Comment: Para mi la clave ha sido la función didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken